# Close lid to sleep just about and open lid to wake up asap without requiring password if done soon enough

Tags: windows-8, laptop, windows-8.1, sleep, power-management

I am sure at some point this tablet-like laptop was doing the thing I've briefly described in the title. That is, within the first couple of months that I've started using this thing.

I am using a Samsung Ativ 7 notebook (XE700T1C) on Windows 8.1. I was probably still using Windows 8 when my computer behaved like that. Let me describe it a little further:

Closing the lid was putting my computer on a sleep-like state, *sleep-like* because it was slightly different than what happens when I press/pressed the power button which puts my computer into a state that I really know as sleep. Here are the two and only differences I've noticed, that I'm missing:

- Opening the lid back on during that state used to wake my computer up. For example,

  - If I were to press the power button and then close the lid, opening the lid wouldn't wake the computer up.
  - If I were to just directly close the lid, opening the lid would wake the computer up.
- Getting up from that state didn't require me to draw my password, swiping the lock-screen up was enough.

  - Same side-notes apply to this one as well.

So it was like a mixture of *sleep* state and the *display turned off* state. Like the sleep state, the power light was off, the music would stop and computer seemingly put to sleep. Like the display turned off state, it would require only the lock-screen to be swiped up to get back on the track. And there's also the waking up as the lid gets opened functionality.

Are there settings to change, registry keys to edit to achieve this? Or was it just a magical state that won't ever come back?

Comment: I am struggling to follow your request. Do you want to see if there is a way to delay the computer entering sleep on lid close?

Comment: @duhamp Not exactly and quite contrary. I want it to enter a state which is like the sleep state, with the key differences being that it should wake up when the lid gets raised as well as it shouldn't require password to get past beyond the lock-screen; asap, w/o delay. Though after a while that state should turn into a sleep, say after 15/30 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pull out the right sidebar and pick settings, there's a menu item to go to your Control Panel. From there, access power options, and change your current plan settings. In the plan settings, you can adjust advanced options via the menu on the left.

From what I understand, under "Power buttons and lid" you will want to set the lid option to Sleep, and set the Power Button action to Hibernate.
If you want the lid option to transition into the power button option, you'll also want to go to "Sleep" and either enable Hybrid Sleep or set a timer for "Hibernate after" (which starts counting from when the computer is idle, not when it goes to sleep).
And you will also want to set require password on wake to off as well.

This should get you to your desired configuration. Unless you're running Windows 8 RT; I haven't even seen one of those so no idea how different they are.

Some elaboration:
Sleep puts your computer in a low power state, feeding power only to RAM and input devices, with periodic mini-wakes to check on scheduled tasks. Any action from input devices will wake the computer (which includes opening the lid). Waking from this state is usually faster, as your computer's state is still in RAM, and the computer only needs to reinitialize your other devices.
Hibernate saves your computer state to disk, and powers everything off. The only way to "wake" from this point is to power on the device. It takes a little longer to wake because it must read everything off disk into memory, and disk is the slowest data device.

Additionally, sleep usually doesn't need a password because it functions more like a screen saver than a screen lock. Hibernate requires password because it's as if you rebooted your computer, except it reopened all your applications into the state before power-off.

Comment: I'm going to accept this, since it really will grant me the behaviour I was after. Also fot that it has a thorough step by step explanation, even though I didn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

To power on when lid opens, you may need to change BIOS settings. This helped me with HP ZBook. Look at this thread

http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/General-Troubleshooting/Toshiba-Satellite-C850-wont-power-on/m-p/477621/highlight/true#M58744

Answer (score -1):

Did you take a look at advanced power plan configuration ? This is where you want to go, from there you can configure what the computer do when you close the lid, you can control the level of sleep for each actions, and you can control if the password should be asked again when the computer wake from any of the sleep levels.

Note that the computer may won't ask for the password if the screen was off (different from computer sleeping)

Comment: Well, of course I have. There I don't see any section where I can *"control the level of sleep for each action"* as you claim. *Hibernation*, which you might be trying to say, could maybe thought as a deeper version of *Sleep* as the name suggests; yet, as I've said, I'm looking for a more subtle version of it, and not as subtle as *Do nothing* because I do want it to do some.

Comment: Hibernation is a level of sleep. Maybe your device had a driver that got broken with the 8.1 update and was in charge to turn on/off the screen without sleeping depending on lid position.

Comment: Okay, there are 4 options on what to happen when I close the lid: *Do nothing*, *Sleep*, *Hibernation*, *Shut down*. You say that Hibernation is a level of Sleep, fine, I wouldn't take it that way for sure, but whatever, fine. Does any of those 4 options have any resemblance to how I described the state I'm looking for?

Answer (score -2):

There should be an option under your Control *Panel* to Control your Lid. You can set Duration before an effect *kicks in*.

SysInternals and a few tools allow you to *mess* with your system.

You can disable the Sleep Option if you want.

I suggest to keep the Re-Authentication if you use the computer in a Workplace.

There's an option to lock your computer when in sleep. Once your computers wakes, you will receive a black screen asking you to insert your password. This way, your computer can't be hijacked in any way. Nothing bad should happen to it while you have your back turned. :)

Sysinternals give you many shells allowing you to play music with system sounds or controlling the parameters in lid like how much time wait before it is initialized.

Comment: Excuse me, but I couldn't understand this at many levels. What is my Control Open? What exactly is/are SysInternals, and how exactly should I make use of it to solve my problem? I already am happy with re-authentication after sleep, although this is just my personal computer. However, what I'm after at is not the sleep, and that is only when I close the lid; the computer shall still sleep when I press the power button.